# CultureInfo with fallback routing to another language

Tags: c#, .net, localization

Our company needs a localization/translation behavior which allows incomplete (**ResX**) resources.
If a String

1. isn't available in italian
2. fall back to the next roman language, like french
3. fall back to our invariant (in this case: german)

The easiest approach was a **custom CultureInfo**.

```
/// <summary>
/// A <see cref="CultureInfo" /> which switches to another language instead of  <see cref="CultureInfo.InvariantCulture" />.
/// </summary>
public class FallbackCultureInfo : CultureInfo
{
    private static readonly List<FallbackCultureInfo> CultureInfos = new List<FallbackCultureInfo>();
    private readonly CultureInfo fallback;
    private CultureInfo determinedParent;

    public override CultureInfo Parent
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.determinedParent != null)
            {
                return this.determinedParent;
            }

            var originalParent = base.Parent;
            if (Object.Equals(originalParent, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) && (this.fallback != null))
            {
                return this.determinedParent = this.fallback;
            }

            if (this.fallback == null)
            {
                return this.determinedParent = originalParent;
            }

            this.determinedParent = FallbackCultureInfo.Build(originalParent.Name, this.fallback.Name);
            return this.determinedParent;
        }
    }


    private FallbackCultureInfo(String name, CultureInfo fallback = null) : base(name)
    {
        this.fallback = fallback;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Builds a <see cref="CultureInfo"/> with a custom fallback behavior, which switsches to 
    /// another language before it gets <see cref="CultureInfo.InvariantCulture"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    /// CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = FallbackCultureInfo.Build("it-CH", "fr-CH", "de-CH");
    /// </example>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Due to a missing <see cref="CultureInfo" />.operator== we have to ensure a unique instance per name on our own.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="name">Name of our culture, like "en-US"</param>
    /// <param name="fallbacks">Fallback stack, like "en-GB", "fr-FR"</param>
    /// <returns>The build <see cref="CultureInfo"/>.</returns>
    public static FallbackCultureInfo Build(String name, params String[] fallbacks)
    {
        lock (FallbackCultureInfo.CultureInfos)
        {
            return FallbackCultureInfo.QueuedBuild(new[] { name }.Concat(fallbacks).Reverse());
        }
    }

    private static FallbackCultureInfo QueuedBuild(IEnumerable<String> names)
    {
        FallbackCultureInfo result = null;
        FallbackCultureInfo lastFallback = null;
        foreach (var name in names)
        {
            result = FallbackCultureInfo.CultureInfos.FirstOrDefault(ci => String.Equals(ci.Name, name));
            if (result != null)
            {
                lastFallback = result;
                continue;
            }

            result = lastFallback = new FallbackCultureInfo(name, lastFallback);
            FallbackCultureInfo.CultureInfos.Add(result);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

---

```
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = FallbackCultureInfo.Build("it-CH", "fr-CH", "de-CH");
```

Works like a charm at a first glance.

But because it is located at a general .Net position, I would like to ask for other opinions about this way to solve the problem. Has anyone done a similiar approach which failed somehow - or even if you havent - do so see any issues with it?

Comment: One issue I can see happening, that can't quite be mitigated in code, is that "if a string isn't available in culture X", it means the .resx file is literally missing the resource key for that string - and whether a resource key is present or not in a .resx file pretty much depends on your localization workflow. Finding missing keys in a .resx file is a royal PITA - I find the default fallback mechanism "good enough" (falls back to the "main" .resx file); I'd find it rather annoying to set my UI to `it-CH` and have half the UI actually rendered in `fr-CH` with a bit of `de-CH` sprinkled in.

Comment: Yes, it tends to become a translation tohuvabohu by design. But that's a part of the requested solution - translation isn't a part of our development, so it's better to have a language near to the requested language than a completely different to reduce the PITA from user perspective.

Comment: You're solving the wrong problem. As @Mat'sMug alluded you could fix this by simplifiying the job for your translators to provide full and accurate translations. FWIW for a project spawned from this community we had a similar problem and I wrote a [small tool](https://github.com/Vogel612/TranslationHelper) to fill up unused keys and mark them with a special background color ..

Comment: I've already suggested to use https://resxresourcemanager.codeplex.com/ for program resources / translations. 

But both of this tools assist you only at the developers point of view.

The solution is intended give a better translation at runtime to a user - either the translator or a user which wants to translate just parts of the whole application to his own language.
It's a *feature*, not a problem.

Comment: @Kelon Your code has (at least) two major bugs that I discovered - see answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Bugs

So, some interesting bugs. If I specify two cultures that have the same invariant, but are different versions it creates really unpleasant circumstances. (Infinite loops, anyone?)

```
var cultureInfo2 = FallbackCultureInfo.Build("en-GB", "en-US", "fr-CH");
```

That creates an infinite loop when rooting through the parent.
 So does:

```
var cultureInfo2 = FallbackCultureInfo.Build("en-GB", "fr-CH", "fr-FR", "de-CH");
```

Why does this matter? I could see a *very real* use case being:

```
cultureInfo = FallbackCultureInfo.Build("en-AU", "en-GB", "en-US");
```

(Use the Australian English culture, if you can't find it there use Great Britain English culture, if you can't find it there use the United States English culture.) Though, using the neutral (`en`) as the second in line *may* very well solve that problem with most strings, but it's still a possibility that this chain could be used and is now broken.

Of course, it's not consistent because of your `static` member there.

```
var cultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
cultureInfo = FallbackCultureInfo.Build("it-CH", "fr-CH", "de-CH");
cultureInfo = FallbackCultureInfo.Build("en-GB", "fr-FR", "de-CH");
```

When looking through all the parents of that second culture set, I don't get the correct tree.

> ```
> en-GB
> en
> fr-CH
> fr
> de-CH
> de
> ```

But *I specified* `fr-FR` for the second fallback!?!?!?!

Of course, we can get even more interesting results with a few other options:

```
cultureInfo = FallbackCultureInfo.Build("it-CH", "fr-CH", "de-CH");
cultureInfo = FallbackCultureInfo.Build("fr-CH", "it-CH", "de-CH");
```

> ```
> fr-CH
> fr
> de-CH
> de
> ```

Wait, what? Where did `it-CH` go?

```
cultureInfo = FallbackCultureInfo.Build("it-CH", "fr-CH", "de-CH");
cultureInfo = FallbackCultureInfo.Build("fr-CH");
```

> ```
> fr-CH
> fr
> de-CH
> de
> ```

Ah, I guess I really did need `de-CH` after all.

While both of these bugs are pretty major, for your situation they're really not something you would look for. You are specifically switching between languages that have different parents, and you're only creating one `FallbackCultureInfo`. (Which is *probably* the most likely scenario.)

---

### Review

In C# we prefer the `string` alias instead of the `String` type.

Other than that, I have no real issues with the structure of your code, but I do have an issue with how you solved the problem.

---

### Alternate Implementation

From what understand [of the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.parent(v=vs.110).aspx), you should be able to get away with making this a lot simpler:

> The cultures have a hierarchy in which the parent of a specific culture is a neutral culture, the parent of a neutral culture is the InvariantCulture, and the parent of the InvariantCulture is the invariant culture itself. The parent culture encompasses only the set of information that is common among its children.
>
> If the resources for the specific culture are not available in the system, the resources for the neutral culture are used. If the resources for the neutral culture are not available, the resources embedded in the main assembly are used. For more information on the resource fallback process, see Packaging and Deploying Resources in Desktop Apps.

Basically, you should be able to just work with the `Parent` property and build from there.

```
public class NewFallbackCultureInfo : CultureInfo
{
    public NewFallbackCultureInfo FallbackCulture { get; }

    public NewFallbackCultureInfo(string name, params string[] names)
        : base(name)
    {
        if (names.Length > 0)
        {
            FallbackCulture = new NewFallbackCultureInfo(this, names);
        }
    }

    private NewFallbackCultureInfo(CultureInfo sourceCulture, params string[] names)
        : base(sourceCulture.Parent.Name)
    {
        var newNames = new string[names.Length - 1];

        for (int i = 1; i < names.Length; i++)
        {
            newNames[i - 1] = names[i];
        }

        FallbackCulture = new NewFallbackCultureInfo(names[0], newNames);
    }

    public override CultureInfo Parent => FallbackCulture ?? base.Parent;
}
```

Note that we also built this without the `.Build` pattern, and relied instead on constructors. It's more natural this way, and preserves the original `CultureInfo` usage.

The only downside I see is that the original parent chain *may* not be preserved, if it goes more than one level.

We can fix that by modifying our `private` constructor:

```
private NewFallbackCultureInfo(CultureInfo sourceCulture, params string[] names)
    : base(sourceCulture.Parent.Name)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(base.Parent.Name))
    {
        var newNames = new string[names.Length - 1];

        for (int i = 1; i < names.Length; i++)
        {
            newNames[i - 1] = names[i];
        }

        FallbackCulture = new NewFallbackCultureInfo(names[0], newNames);
    }
    else
    {
        FallbackCulture = new NewFallbackCultureInfo(this, names);
    }
}
```

When tracing the `Parent` chain, I found that the chain produced by my version is identical to the chain produced by your version, except it doesn't break when tested against the criteria that broke your version.

---

I apologize if this felt brutal, but I was actually having *a bit* of fun with it after I realized *what* was happening.

Comment: Thanks for your review! That's what I requested, it's just code, and it doesn't feel brutal :)
Okay - string/String - I agree, but thats just a team internal agreement  for syntax highlighting (Which I don't like as well)
The static/Build()-pattern is necessary to achieve instance uniqueness as described in its xmldoc. At the beginning, I used the same way you did. But Microsoft distributes with a missing operator== in CultureInfo, while the ResourceManager uses it, which leads to a broken resource stack.
I'll review the other parts of your review as soon as my current work has been done .

Comment: @Kelon Care to elaborate on what you mean by 'instance uniqueness', and 'broken resource stack'?

Comment: Due to the missing operator== overload, the ResourceManager does a ReferenceEquals()-Call instead of an Equals()-Call to find a loaded ResourceSet whenever it searches for a fallback resource value. 
To reproduce this problem, just change the CurrentUICulture a second time after requesting the resource. 
Mhm, But Okay, you're creating all fallbacks inside of the constructor. 
Perhaps thats already a good way to fill this gap - thanks again.

Comment: This answer has been selected as the winner of [Best of Code Review 2016 — Exterminator](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/7142/9357).